# Add a new cookie from outside of chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, cookies

I have this command which enters the user in a chrome window to my site.

```
chrome.exe --incognito --app="https://www.example.com/home"
```

I want the user to log into their account once (both the software and the site require login to access services)

The problem I'm running into is that I want to attach cookies to the chrome command

I want any way to send cookies to Chrome

I've found tools like [ChromeCookiesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html) but they don't write a new cookie

Can I find someone to help me?

Comment: Have you used the search function?

Answer (score -1):

Doing Cookie Import/Export requires third-party extensions to Chrome.

See the article
[Cookie Import/Export: Quick Guide + Top 5 Tools](https://gologin.com/blog/cookie-import-export)
which lists : EditThisCookie, Swap My cookies, Cookie Editor,
Cookie-Editor, Export History / Bookmarks to JSON / CSV / XLS.

You will find in the article a review of each extension.

---

Chrome stores its cookies in an SQLite database, so a program is required.
The database is found in the file `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`.

To import data into this database will require an SQLite database
manager, perhaps SQLite itself.

Comment: Isn't there a way from outside of chrome?

Comment: It should be easily possible from Python with connection to SQLite when the db is not encrypted.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain ?